# Scripting arbitrary menubar itemns

Tags: applescript, ui

So I really want to fix this applescript I'm working on. I would like to be able to click an arbitrary item in an arbitrary submenu of an arbitrary menu in any application. Here's where I've gotten:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process activeApp
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        click
    end tell
end tell
```

The problem I'm getting is when I add that second "of menu bar item 1". It worked just fine up until I got to that point and now I don't know what to do? I'm pretty new to UI scripting and applescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hierarchy of the `menu bar` object goes like this:

```
menu bar > menu bar item > menu > menu item [ > menu > menu item [...] ]
```

where the square brackets indicate possible sub-menus, should they exist.

Therefore, if you change this line:

```
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
```

to this:

```
    tell menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
```

it will work.

This, of course, will always click the Apple () menu, which is `menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1` for all applications in which the menu bar exists and is visible (although it belongs to whichever application is frontmost, so attempting to ask another application process to click this item will throw an error).

If you wish to click an arbitrary menu item in the menu bar to reveal its menu, you need to replace the index number `1` of the `menu bar item` with a random value, but one that does not exceed the number of available `menu bar items`.

To get the number of menu bar items, use the `count` command:

```
    set N to count menu bar items of menu bar 1 of activeApp
```

(You can omit `of activeApp` if the command is placed inside a `tell process activeApp` block.)

To get a random number between 1 and `N`, use the `random number` command:

```
    set i to random number from 1 to N
```

Putting that all together, your new command will look something like this:

```
    tell menu bar item i of menu bar 1 to click
```

Now each time you run the script, a random menu bar item will be clicked causing its menu to appear.

To go even further, and get your script to click a random `menu item`, you can apply exactly the same principles as above, bearing in mind the hierarchy I laid out at the top.

So, after retrieving a random menu bar item, next determine the maximum number of `menu items` and generate a random number less than or equal to this maximum:

```
    set M to count menu items of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
    set j to random number from 1 to M
```

Then you can click it:

```
    click menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
```

Applying the same principles to any sub-menus that exist for that particular menu item, you'll end up with this:

```
    set L to count menu items of menu 1 of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
    set k to random number from 1 to L
    click menu item k of menu 1 of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
```

However, you'll find that this—more often than not—will throw an error when trying to `set L`.  This is because not all menu items will have sub-menus, and in the instances where no sub-menu exists, asking AppleScript to count the number of menu items [in a non-existent sub-menu] is not a sensible command.

There are two ways to handle this.  Either wrap those lines in a `try...end try` error-catching block, like this:

```
    try
        set L to count menu items of menu 1 of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
        set k to random number from 1 to L
        click menu item k of menu 1 of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
    end try
```

or `count` the number of (sub-)menus of `menu item j`, and only proceed if this number is greater than 0:

```
    count menus of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1

    if the result > 0 then
        set L to count menu items of menu 1 of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
        set k to random number from 1 to L
        click menu item k of menu 1 of menu item j of menu 1 of menu bar item i of menu bar 1
    end if
```

And so on, and so on...

#### Finally...

It's unlikely you will know precisely how many levels deep a particular menu tree goes: how many sub-menus within sub-menus exist for a particular menu item ?  The answer is at least 0, but with no given maximum unless you check in advance yourself.

Luckily, we can AppleScript to do the checking for us.  After picking a random `menu bar item`, every child that spawns from this (looking at the hierarchy I showed you at the top) is a `menu` followed by a `menu item`.  The `menu` object, as you'll have noticed, only comes in singular count, so will always be referenced as `menu 1`.  The `menu items` come in plural, and these are the items that need counting.

So, quite simply, having chosen a random `menu bar item`, we get AppleScript to do the following:

1. `count` the number of `menu items` it contains;
2. If this value is 0, then there are no sub-menus, so we can just click the item we have;
3. If the value is greater than 0, then choose a random one;
4. `count` the number of `menu items` **this** one contains;
5. If this value is 0, just click it;
6. If the value is greater than 0, then choose a random one;
7. etc..

This process is a loop that can keep going for as many sub-menus that it finds.  And that's what this code does:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell (the first application process ¬
            whose frontmost is true)
            
            set m to it
            set _m to the menu bar items of menu bar 1
            
            repeat
                if not (exists _m) then exit repeat
                
                set i to random number from 1 to (count _m)
                
                set m to item i of _m
                set _m to a reference to menu items of menu 1 of m
            end repeat
            
            click m
            
        end tell
```

**Caveat:** The horizontal lines that separate sections of a menu are also classed as `menu items`, as are any menu items that are disabled.  These, when clicked, don't do anything.

---

**BE CAREFUL:**  ***Clicking a menu item randomly before you know what it does can result in some undesirable outcomes.  For instance, you may accidentally quit the front application; you may delete a file or eject a disk if the script runs whilst* Finder *is at the front; or you may log out or shut down your computer.***

Comment: Thank you for your help! How do I select, but not click, an item (i.e., it highlights and I can select a different one). Is there a "show," but not click command.

Comment: @user279242 You can use the `select` command in place of `click`, which will highlight the menu item in question as if you were hovering the mouse pointer over it.  If a menu item has a sub menu, then you can issue a `click` command to show its sub-menu.